# JAXB : annotation. Exception raised

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb

I have a REST service which serialize into the response some objects.
My entities ares annotated with XML but JAXB raised an illegalAnnotationExceptions...

Here the entities :

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "icns")
public class IcnList {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<IcnElement> icns;

    public List<IcnElement> getIcns() {
        return icns;
    }

    public void setIcns(List<IcnElement> icns) {
        this.icns = icns;
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "icn")
public class IcnElement {

    private String status;

    private String revision;

    private String icnName;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public String getIcnName() {
        return icnName;
    }

    public void setIcnName(String icnName) {
        this.icnName = icnName;
    }

}
```

Here the exception :

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "icns"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.xx.model.IcnList.getIcns()
        at com.xx.model.IcnList
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.List com.xx.model.IcnList.icns
        at com.xx.model.IcnList
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem ? and why ? 
I made some research but I'm totally lost...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JAXB will treat public properties and annotated fields as mapped.  The conflict is occurring in your mapping because JAXB thinks you have the following mappings:

1. A field called `icns` that is mapped to the element `icns`.
2. A property called `icns` that is mapped to the element `icns`.

This is causing your name conflict.  You can eliminate the conflict by annotating the property (get or set method):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "icns")
public class IcnList {

    private List<IcnElement> icns;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public List<IcnElement> getIcns() {
        return icns;
    }

    public void setIcns(List<IcnElement> icns) {
        this.icns = icns;
    }

}
```

Or if you wish to annotate the field you can use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the class level.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "icns")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IcnList {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<IcnElement> icns;

    public List<IcnElement> getIcns() {
        return icns;
    }

    public void setIcns(List<IcnElement> icns) {
        this.icns = icns;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the root element

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "icns")
```

or, this element:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
private List<IcnElement> icns;
```

Use `@XmlType(name = "icn" ....)` instead

Comment: I already tried to change the name of the attribute, but no effect.

Comment: Have you tried removing the annotation from IcnElement class?? Use @XmlType(name = "icn" ....) instead.